# Inheritance between Point class and Circle class

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, geometry, point

I just got into OOP-style in python and was playing around with classes. For this particular problem I want my `class Circle` to be a subclass of my `class Point`. But it is also important to have a equality check for a certain tolerance. However, I just do not know how to declare the circle variables as follows `__init__(self, circle, radius)`. On top of that I do get a tuple error due to the equality function (I know this is due to tuples not being mutable). I have tried a myriad of ways, but I'll just paste the simplest form, just for the sake of echoing the idea more clearly:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x= x
        self.y= y

    def __eq__(self, other):
    if abs(self.x-other.x)<0.00001 and abs(self.y-other.y)< 0.00001:
        return True
    else:
        return False

class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, centre, radius):
        self.centre = Point(x,y)
        self.radius= radius

    def equals(self, other):
        return Point.__eq__(other)<0.00001 and abs(self.radius-other.radius)<0.00001
```

Is there some fundamental misunderstand on my part, or is the thing I am aiming for just impossible/not smart? Any sort of help is appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Are you *sure* you actually want `circle` to be a subclass of `point`. Unless you consider a point to be a circle of zero radius (and I don't), I'm not convinced that's the best way to do it. Better that a circle be its own class (or a subclass of some form of `shape`, from which `point` could also inherit if you want to be able to treat them both as a single base class) that *contains* a `point` rather than inherits from `point`. In other words, `has-a` rather than `is-a`.

Comment: @paxdiablo That's what I initially did, but then struggled I with the equals function. It would either be too messy, or I would get the tuple error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You've written a great question, so I'm not certain why it was downvoted. I fixed it, and am confident the community will help a new user who took the time to show his effort as you did. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One *immediate* problem lies here:

```
def __init__(self, centre, radius):
    self.centre = Point(x,y)
```

You pass in `centre` (presumably a `Point` type) but reference the non-existing variables `x` and `y`.

---

In any case, I'm not convinced it's correct to consider a circle as being a type of point - it doesn't seem to fit with real-world modelling.

It may *seem* logical at first glance, since a circle *does* generally have a centre and radius, but think of what that would mean for other shapes such as a rectangle. A rectangle that was derived from a point would also have to have *other* points to specify the other three corners (as the simplest implementation) and it really makes no sense to treat *one* of those points as special.

I think it would be better to have a common base class of both point *and* circle (and every other shape that you need) and modify `Circle` so that it `has-a` point rather than `is-a` point.

That *could* be as simple as:

```
class Shape:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
    def type(self):
        return "Shape"

class Point(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def type(self):
        return "Point"
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other.type() != self.type(): return False
        return abs(self.x - other.x) < 0.00001 and abs(self.y - other.y) < 0.00001

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.centre = Point(x,y)
        self.radius = radius
    def type(self):
        return "Circle"
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other.type() != self.type():
            return False
        return self.centre == other.centre and abs(self.radius - other.radius) < 0.00001
```

Note the default behaviour of the common base class which assumes equality is always false, even for itself, so don't think you can get any rational results if you try to compare shapes :-). Each sub-class then overrides that to check that:

- the types are compatible<sup>(a)</sup>; and
- the relevant fields are matching (to some degree of accuaracy as per your original code).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> At the moment, this is checking that the types are *identical,* but you could equally modify it so that a point and a zero-radius circle (or a rectangle with four identical corner points or any other zero-dimensional "real shape") are considered identical.

Or a rectangle that is actually a square may be considered equal to a square , and so on.

Comment: For some reason I had a faulty understating of inheritance between classes. This was very helpful and thank you for the insight!